# Finding lowest positive number in array - Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to find the lowest positive number in the array using assembly and c, but I don't get the correct result.

My assembly code:

```
    bits 64

    section .data


        section .text

    global lowest_positive

lowest_positive:
    enter 0,0
        movsx rsi, esi                         ; t_N
        mov rcx, 0                             ; index=0
        mov eax, [rdi + 0]                     ; min=t_array[0]

.backfor:

        cmp rcx, rsi                           ; index < t_N
        jge .endfor 

        cmp [rdi + rcx * 4], byte '0'          ; t_array[index] > 0
        jle .min
        inc rcx

.min:
       
        cmp eax, [rdi + rcx * 4]                ; min > t_array[index]
        jge .skipmin
        mov eax, [rdi + rcx * 4]                ; min = t_array[index]


.skipmin:

        inc rcx
        jmp .backfor

                    
.endfor:
       
        leave
        ret
```

My c code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int lowest_positive( long *t_pole, int t_len );


int main()
{
     long lon_array[] = {655,543,-453,234,8743,-34345,19345,2044,5545,43};
     printf("lowest pos: %d\n", lowest_positive(lon_array, 10) );



}
```

I should get 43 as result but I got 8743 back. Please check my code and help me understand I'm new to assembly.

Comment: First of all, `long` is a 64-bit type in x86-64 System V, but you're operating on 32-bit dwords.  And you're skipping to the next number when the low byte is less than ASCII `'0'` (0x30).  (Try two negative numbers in a row once you fix that: you'll still accept the second one without checking it for negative.)  I assume you were trying to check the whole number for negative, but you set the operand-size to `byte` instead of `qword` for some reason.  Load a qword into a register like a normal person instead of loading 2 or 3 times; that's what registers are for.

Comment: BTW, this would auto-vectorize fairly decently with SSE2 `pcmpgtd` and manual blending.  Or for dword (`int32_t`) with [SSE4.1 for `pminud`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pminud:pminuq), *very* efficiently.  (An unsigned compare treats negative numbers as large unsigned.  If you need to treat `0` as non-positive, subtract 1 before `pminud` so it becomes UINT_MAX).  For `long`, you'd need SSE4.2 pcmpgtq or to emulate it in terms of pcmpgtd (`vpminuq` requires AVX-512).